# Unable to install PsychoPy module in Python

Tags: python, psychopy

I tried to install the psychopy module in python, using Anaconda Prompt and `python -m pip install PsychoPy` and it gave me error messages I have no idea how to interpret:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59jM4.png)

followed by a bunch of white text mostly starting with "Requirement already satisfied: [...]" and two other red walls of text "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: [...]" (I can also post pictures of them, if needed)

Additional Info:

- I use a Windows 10, Version 21H2, x64-based System
- For Python (3.8.8) I use Sypder
- Anaconda Navigator is Version 2.0.3
- I also have the PsychoPy Standalone (Coder, Runner & Builder) installed (version 2022.2.0)

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Please also tell me if I did this question-thing right, this is my first time posting here and I don't know the etiquette yet

Comment: here is a quick guide to good question asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: if you are using anaconda, you might need to use `conda` instead of `pip`...

Answer (score 0):

This is not for sure.
Maybe you already solve this problem.
I have experienced some problem of psychopy.
So, I hope this is helpful for you and many other researchers with psychopy.

First, update conda will solve many kind of problems.
'''
conda update --all
'''

Second, In anaconda environment using 'conda' command is recommendation.
In anaconda environment use(except for impossible) 'conda' command is recommended. Generally, mixed use of 'pip' and 'conda' command is not matter. BUT, SOMETIMES, this could occur minor error like this question.

Third, use anaconda virtual environment.
Anaconda provide virtual environment. Initially virtual environment looks confused but, this could safe and secured develop your experiment program.

Lastly, this probelem.
In the middle of your error message. "requires-python>=3.6" <- maybe this means your environment is not appropriate the environment. but your environment is 3.8.8.
For now this is just hypothesis. I think your environment have more than 2 of python could be installed. So, delete all python and reinstall the anaconda and use virtual environment could be safe.

I haven't used this community for a long time so I don't know the etiquette. If I was rude, thank you for your understanding.